# How to change this to String.Format in C#

Tags: c#, string, command-line, ffmpeg, code-formatting

**Original**

```
string strCommandLineArgs = (((("-i" + " ") + strVideoPath + " -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s ") + intWidth.ToString() + "x") + intHeight.ToString() + " ") + strImagePath + " -ss 2";
```

**I have done this**

```
string strCommandLineArgs = string.Format("-i {0} -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s {1}x{2} {3} -ss 2", strVideoPath, intWidth, intHeight, strImagePath);
```

I cant find the difference in use of `(` and `)` in string.

Comment: not sure what you're asking, the second line of code answers your title question.

Comment: I having problem in this cmd line args that's why I asked in Community so that if anyone finds any problem in this... Thanks to all for reply

Comment: You might want to ask another question and describe the actual problem you're having. If you can't easily find a solution on your own, asking about it without narrowing it down to where you think the problem is might lead to some unbiased insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. The brackets don't add anything special to the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is silly:

```
string strCommandLineArgs = (((("-i" + " ") + strVideoPath + " -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s ") + intWidth.ToString() + "x") + intHeight.ToString() + " ") + strImagePath + " -ss 2";
```

it's like writing:

```
((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)
```

you can write it as:

```
string strCommandLineArgs = "-i" + " " + strVideoPath + " -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s " + intWidth.ToString() + "x" + intHeight.ToString() + " " + strImagePath + " -ss 2";
```